# presentViewController with multiple view controllers issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, presentmodalviewcontroller, uimodaltransitionstyle

I have view controllers A, B, C, D. Current view controller is A.

I need to present D from A. And then when I dismiss D I should see C. When I dismiss C, I should see B.

It's easy to implement with navigation controller stack, but I don't know if it's possible to implement this with modal view controllers stack.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: The best solution I see right now is to present without animation B from A, then present without animation C from B, and then D from C. So user will see only D without animation, but behavior with animation is better

Comment: In my opinion the thing to think about here is not can you do this, but **should** you do this. The view hierarchy is important so the user understands where they are in your app. If the user goes from view A to view B, they expect that when they go back, they'll get back to view A. Unless your app has a clear indication that this won't be the case I wouldn't recommend going down this route from a usability point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
First set property to those all view controller I mean like:
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIViewController * viewa,*viewb,*viewc,*viewd;

You can switch the viewcontroller like:

[self presentViewController: viewb animated:NO completion:nil];

So add this statement from wherever you want to change the viewcontroller.

Try this.

I am doing the same in my app and its working.

Or when u want to dismiss view then use this:-

[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];